# Bindings between controllers - how to avoid redundant null?

Tags: ember.js

```
App.MainController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['my']
});

App.MyController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['main'],
    mainControllerBinding: 'controllers.main'
});
```

This of course doesn't work as expected. But this:

```
App.MyController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['main'],
    mainController: null,
    mainControllerBinding: 'controllers.main'
});
```

that is setting `null`, does. The problem is when you try to set a few more bindings and what you see is a bunch of redundant nulls preceding the real bindings.

Is there a known way of avoiding it and be a bit more DRY?

---

### Edit#1

The approved solution helped me to kill two birds with one stone. It turns out that previously [this wasn't possible](http://jsfiddle.net/gqSMU/12/) - I got the errors all the time:

```
Error while loading route: RangeError
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Please note that it might be impossible to run this example as it crashes Chrome.

But the new approach made it possible with no effort! http://jsfiddle.net/gqSMU/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
App.MyController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['main'],
  mainController: Em.computed.alias('controllers.main')
});
```

Comment: Can you expand on how this works to resolve the requester's question?

Comment: Sure, there seems to be some issues related to binding order in Ember, and everyone else is pushing us to use computed properties instead of bindings, it looks like bindings are going to be deprecated soon in favor of CP. And if you go to http://emberjs.com/api/ you'll find that there are many other 'operators' for 'computed', so, you have many options to choose from.

Comment: yes I think that some browsers have this issue, FYI https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1164

Comment: @fanta thank you for your help. Things in Ember happens very fast. I kind of don't like it. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1164#issuecomment-23602633

Comment: @fanta I'd like to express my gratitude! You helped me to solve another problem - please take a look at the updated question. :)

Comment: :) nice, your example indeed killed my browser. Things are changing fast in Ember, but that's because developers want it to be more stable and faster, they're doing many things before the final V1, there are a few changes coming in ember data as well.